# npm module "gmail-send" - Catch receiver email in callback

Tags: node.js, email, callback, gmail

This is my variant of sending emails but nature of this call in asynchronous.
I use webSocket for communication with client and i handle it nice.

I need good solution. I can put shared.id = "userID"; before this.GM(...) and after use it but looks like bad method.

I look in debugger values :

*** < TAG >250 2.0.0 OK 1541108492 q2sm3291021wrx.77 - gsmtp< TAG >***

All method return same result.

Any idea how to inject or override callback...

```
 SEND(subject, connector) {
    this.GM({
      subject: subject,
      // files: [filepath],
    }, function(err, res) {
      if (err !== null) {
        console.log("Sender callback returned: err:", err);
        return err;
      } else {
        console.log('Sender callback returned: ', res, "this is instance ", connector);
        shared.myBase.onMailSend("mail sent successfully");
      }
    });
  }
```

On success callback i get :

> 250 2.0.0 OK 1541108492 q2sm3291021wrx.77 - gsmtp